# play online mp3 music in python

Tags: python-2.7, module, audio-player

I'm writing an app in python which inclues playing online mp3 resouces , the mp3 file is represented by an url  like http://xxxxx.mp3, Is there any suitable modules can handle this?
I'm using Ubuntu system and python 2.7.2.

Comment: Anything you tried yet ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor mp3play does not support Linux system and pyMedia seems dead after 2006

Comment: I mean programming. playing MP3 file in Python is not rocket science. Try to Google.

Comment: I've tried that, only rocket science problems are welcomed here?

Comment: If you tried, post your codes here. Read FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq .